# Compare password of webpages_membership in SQL Server query

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a web application done in ASP.NET MVC 4. It has users, that are stored in SQL Server database in tables `webpages_UserProfile` and `webpages_Membership`, etc.

I have another application, and what I need to do is to query the table `webpages_Membership`, where password of users are stored encrypted, and compare them to a plain text password.

So I tried doing something like

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM webpages_Membership 
 WHERE PwdCompare('mypasswordsend', Password) = 1
```

But it doesn't works. I know the column is a `nvarchar(128)`.

How can I compare it?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the second argument to `PwdCompare` (emphasis mine):

> password_hash
>   
> Is the encryption hash of a password. password_hash is ****varbinary(128)****.

So, if your column is storing the password in plain text, or is storing a string representation of the binary hash, it's not going to work. You should either change the column to be correct or you will need to convert it first, e.g. check this script:

```
SELECT PWDENCRYPT(N'mypassword');
```

Yields:

> 0x0200D422C0365A196E308777C96CBEF3854818601DDB516CADA98DBDF6A5F23922DC0FADD29B806121EA1A26AED86F57FCCB4DDF98F0EFBF44CA6BA864E9E58A818785FDDEDF

If we try to compare that value *as a string*, we get 0:

```
SELECT PWDCOMPARE(N'mypassword', N'0x0200D422C0365A196E308777C96CBEF3854818601DDB516CADA98DBDF6A5F23922DC0FADD29B806121EA1A26AED86F57FCCB4DDF98F0EFBF44CA6BA864E9E58A818785FDDEDF');
```

If we try to compare it *as a varbinary value*, we get 1:

```
SELECT PWDCOMPARE(N'mypassword', 0x0200D422C0365A196E308777C96CBEF3854818601DDB516CADA98DBDF6A5F23922DC0FADD29B806121EA1A26AED86F57FCCB4DDF98F0EFBF44CA6BA864E9E58A818785FDDEDF);
```

If you can't fix the table, then you can perform this expensive explicit conversion in your query every time (note that the trailing `,1` is important):

```
SELECT PWDCOMPARE(N'mypassword', 
  CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), N'0x0200D422C0365A196E308777C96CBEF3854818601DDB516CADA98DBDF6A5F23922DC0FADD29B806121EA1A26AED86F57FCCB4DDF98F0EFBF44CA6BA864E9E58A818785FDDEDF'
  , 1));
```

Comment: i tried getting the hash and doing something like pwdcompare('mypassword','thesuperhashJFsdgidfdjdng'), but didnt work too

Comment: @MaximilianoPoggio well what on earth is `'thesuperhashJFsdgidfdjdng'`? That does not look like a hash at all, just a mumbo-jumbo string. If you are storing the password in plain text, stop using the `PWDCOMPARE` function. If you want to store the hash correctly, change the column data type and use `PWDENCRYPT` to store the data (or use your own hashing/comparison algorithms).